# Framework to make Angular Material responsive without CSS know how

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, flexbox

It's been sometime since I worked on building a web application using Angular. Last I worked it was on Angular 4. At that time I used Bootstrap for layout and components.
With this endeavour, I have opted for Angular Material on Angular 9.0.4. But for layout and aligning components, I'm facing a challenge as to what I should use given the fact that I'm not CSS literate. I mean I can handle little bits and pieces for bugs and all by digging my way through the internet but writing CSS for layout and stuff is way out of my league. When I looked up Bootstrap I found people saying it is not the ideal way as it has jQuery based implementation. So I'm here to ask for advice as to what I could pickup and learn fast without having to learn CSS entirely. Thanks.

Comment: That gold saying is false. You can use bootstrap without using its js library.

Comment: @mahan My bad. It was supposed to be "people", not *gold*

Comment: If you like and are comfortable with Bootstrap, libraries like ng-bootstrap provide Angular components that handle the jQuery that Bootstrap uses. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home.